# By using Xamarin Android get DataTable from WCF service (server) will have exception error

Tags: c#, android, wcf, datatable, xamarin

I create one WCF service and upload to Windows Server 2012, 64 bit and two application: Windows Form and Android Xamarin. Windows Form and Android Xamarin will called the same WCF service. Running Windows Form will display the whole datatable nicely. Thanks God ! But running Android will have exception error.

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET

How to get a DataTable from WCF ?

The below is my source code.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        wcfBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        wcfBtn.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.TableName = "GoldenRetrieverTable2";

        DataTable dataTbl = new DataTable();
        dataTbl.TableName = "GoldenRetrieverTable2";

        AdelineService.Service1 wcfService = new AdelineService.Service1();

        dataTbl = wcfService.GetData(dt);
    };
}
```

Kindly please help. I am sure it is due to my way of writting "Android C#" method of get DataTable problem because Windows Forms is display correctly.

Comment: If it's complaining about an internal error, you should have more information on the server side. The UI side of this is completely irrelevant, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable` is poor choice for interoperability and Web Services in general. It's a .NET type and you're making the load that needs to be transferred over the wire unnecessarily heavier. Not only does a `DataTable` object contain data, but it also contains Schema information.

This information is useless to non-Microsoft clients and bloats the size of the data to be transferred. I personally never use `DataTable`, even in .NET to .NET scenarios where I own both ends.

My two recommendations would be:

1. Create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) that holds the information you want from each row and populate an array of these. Send this over the wire instead of a `DataTable`.
2. Unless you are stuck using a SOAP based Web Service, I would recommend creating a RESTful Web Service. My personal experience has been that SOAP isn't the holy grail of interoperability that it was once thought to be.